# Google Sheet Function that matches cell to database and that adds the non present cell values to the database

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am new to Apps Script and I´m trying to automize a google sheet document.

I´m trying to emulate the following function:

```
=if(isnumber(match($G4;Hoja!$C:$C;0));vlookup($G4;Hoja!$C:$F;2;0);"")
```

Then if the if statement is false, I want to copy the value of the respective `$G` cell after the last value I have in the Range `$C:$F` of the `Hoja` tab, and so in the `C` column.

What I'm trying to do is create a functions that finds a match for a cell (`G`) based on database (`C:F`), and that adds the value of the cell (`G`) to the database (`C:F`) if it is not already present.

Comment: Is this what you are asking: read the values in columns C through F and for each value lookup for match in column G. If match is found, then replace the value in the current row for columns C through F?

Comment: With this are you aiming to create a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to be used anywhere on your Spreadhseet that changes ```G``` for any other cell or just to create a function that when you run it on the editor performs that exact operation?